# MapProxy GetFeatureInfo: passing additional parameter to QGIS Server

Tags: getfeatureinfo, qgis-server, mapproxy

I have MapProxy Version 1.12 configured and working very well with QGIS Server 3.10.

I need to use cached layers suporting GetFeatureInfo requests. But I also need to pass to additional parameters to QGIS Server:

```
WITH_GEOMETRY=TRUE&
FI_POINT_TOLERANCE=10&
```

These additional parameters should only be added to the request for GetFeatureInfo requests.

But when I use a MapProxy cached layer, the additional GetFeatureInfo parameters are not passed back to the QGIS Server.

If I issue a GetFeatureInfo request against Mapproxy:

```
http://mapproxy.qgis.demo/mapproxy/service?
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.1.1&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
TRANSPARENT=true&
QUERY_LAYERS=geotuga_costanova_short_house_numbers&
LAYERS=geotuga_costanova_short_house_numbers&
TILED=true&
INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&
WITH_GEOMETRY=TRUE&
FI_POINT_TOLERANCE=10&
X=235&
Y=91&
WIDTH=256&
HEIGHT=256&
SRS=EPSG%3A3763&
STYLES=&
BBOX=-36975%2C120827%2C-36900%2C120902
```

The request if forwarded to QGIS Server as:

```
http://qgis.demo/postgresql/geotuga/public/costanova/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?
transparent=True&
layers=short_house_numbers&
bbox=-36975.0,120827.0,-36900.0,120902.0&
width=256&
height=256&
x=235&
y=91&
query_layers=short_house_numbers&
info_format=application%2Fjson&
format=image%2Fpng&
srs=EPSG%3A3763&
request=GetFeatureInfo&
version=1.1.1&
service=WMS&
styles=
```

The additional parameters do not reach the server.

My source is configured with `featureinfo: true` in `mapproxy.yaml`:

```
  geotuga_costanova:
    type: wms
    wms_opts:
      featureinfo: true
      legendgraphic: true
    req:
      url: http://qgis.demo/postgresql/geotuga/public/costanova/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
      transparent: true
```

How can I have all GetFeatureInfo requests going back to the server with additional parameters?

This is related to this [Custom Vendor Parameters for WMS and Caches](https://bitbucket.org/olt/mapproxy/issues/40/custom-vendor-parameters-for-wms-and) discussion. GetFeatureInfo requests are not cached, so it maybe easier to support.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in req part like that:

```
req:
  [...]
  WITH_GEOMETRY: TRUE
  FI_POINT_TOLERANCE : 10
```

All you request to this WMS GetFeatureInfo will have this parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a URL parameter like this to the server?